# iPhone:How to implement Crash Report functionality in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

Is there any way to save crash log while apps is crashed and also apps is launched at that time Mail Dialogue is display to send the mail with that crash log???? so please tell me any link or any idea to develop this functionality in iPhone...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [QuincyKit](http://quincykit.net/). It is open source and you'll have to setup your own server to collect crash logs.

Comment: +1 for QuincyKit. It gives you almost instant feedback in case anything starts going bad in your app.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need any additional SDK's to view the crash raports. Apple gives you this functionality in their "iTunes Connect" portal. Here is how to access it:

- Log in to [iTunesConnect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com)
- go to "Manage Your Applications"
- choose your application, by clicking on it's name.
- click "View details" button under the Versions table.
- click "Crash Reports" link
- if you don't have reports yet, press "refresh"

That's it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Even if there are known crashing issues in an app you really need a lot of reports in order to have iTunesConnect tell you that there is anything wrong in your app.

Comment: **And** I think if the user has `Don't Send` selected under `Diagnostics & Usage` in there settings, then it may not bee sending crash reports to Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Crittercism worked for me
It can be implemented in few minutes, which is easy and great.

Crittercism supports instant crash reporting to your mail(setting up server is not required)
Detailed report generation which includes the line number where the crash occurred.

Following links helped me:

[Crittercism](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ONp2S9USMNY)

**Note:** Adding DSYM file is recommended(which is responsible for showing the exact line number where crash occurred)

See [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2hv35MisgM)